# How to have a derived class object access values from the base class?

Tags: c++

So I am making this dumb project in C++ and whenever I call data members of the base class from the derived class, I am getting "undesired" values. Sorry for posting almost the entire code as I am not sure which parts  to avoid  :(

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
   public:
    string a[10];
    int b[10];
    void setup()
    {
        a[1]="Hello world";
        b[1]=10;

    }

};
class B:public A
{
    public:
    void test()
    {
        cout<<A::a[1];
        cout<<A::b[1];
    }
};
int main()
{
    A obj;
    B obj2;
    obj.setup();
    obj2.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please convert your program to a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: Done! Changed it into a much simpler code which reproduces the problem :)

Comment: You never initialize the values inside the arrays, so printing them out leads to *undefined behavior*

Comment: Did so in the base class function void setup :( I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: You call `setup` on one object and `test` on another. Try using `obj2.setup();` before `obj2.test();`

Comment: Or, if you don't actually want separate objects to have different member values, but instead want all `A` objects (including objects of type `B`) to share those members, you're looking for `static` members.

Comment: So it works on this example but whenever I am using a friend class the compiler doesnt let me use the same objects for both classes

Comment: @InteserLazim That sounds like a different question.

Comment: Using static it gives me an undefined reference error

Comment: Before doing try & error, you might want to learn the concepts of classes, instances, static variables, declarations and definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
obj.setup();
```

sets the values of the members of `obj`. That has no bearing on the members of `obj2`. Members of `obj2.a` are still default initialized while members of `obj2.b` are still uninitialized.

Use the following instead:

```
B obj;
obj.setup();
obj.test();
```

---

An analogous problem with a simpler `struct`.

```
struct Foo
{
   string a;
   int b;
};

Foo f1 = {"String 1", 10};
Foo f2;
```

Given the above, you expect `f2.a` to be `"String 1"` and `f2.b` to be `10`. That is clearly a false expectation.